# MATLAB precision loss when calling a function

Tags: matlab, precision

I simulated localization of a 2-wheeled robot using Extended Kalman Filter.
In my first version, the core algorithm is inside a while loop as in the following example:

```
function ekfSimulation()

    for i=1:simulationSteps
        % main Algorithm
    end

end
```

In my second version, I implemented the same procedure, except this time the "main Algorithm" inside the loop is called from another function as follows:

```
function ekfSimulation()

    for i=1:simulationSteps

        % call main algorithm from another function
        [output data]=mainAlgorithm(input data)

    end

end

%****************************************************
function [output data]= mainAlgorithm(input data)
    %main Algorithm
end
```

The results in my second version (covariance matrix, Root-Mean-Square-Error) are about 2 times less accurate than in the first version while all other variables are the same.

**QUESTION**
Is it possible that passing and returning variables to and from a function would cause these discrepancies?

Thanks.

Comment: You showed a `for` loop not a `while` loop. Is it possible? No, not directly. What's most likely is that you have a bug and you aren't passing and/or updating the information that you thing that you are. Have you tried debugging? Type `help debug` in your command window. This could be as easy as a variable with the same name or an array getting transposed. Does `input data` depend on `output data` in any way? And, as you're using noise, have you [set a seed for you random number generator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html) to make your results repeatable?

Comment: I will take a look at it again and try to find bugs in it.
The input of current iteration depends on output from previous iterations. All I did was copy-past the code inside the loop and put it in a different function with inputs/outputs.